# Docker ubuntu 18.04 ssh-keyscan

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

Hoping somebody may have already solved this.

I am wanting to upgrade my docker images from `Ubuntu 16.04` to `Ubuntu 18.04`.
Everything seems to be fine except for the following:

```
RUN apt-get install -y ssh
RUN mkdir -p /home/sshkeys
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /home/sshkeys/id_rsa 
RUN touch /home/sshkeys/authorized_keys
RUN cat /home/sshkeys/id_rsa.pub >> /home/sshkeys/authorized_keys
RUN ./etc/init.d/ssh start
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config     
**RUN ssh-keyscan localhost >> /home/postgres/.ssh/known_hosts**
```

With `Ubuntu 16.04` this works fine but in `Ubuntu 18.04` I get the following error when building the image from the `Dockerfile`:

```
Step 36/71 : RUN ssh-keyscan localhost >> /home/postgres/.ssh/known_hosts
 ---> Running in 0f34b430fc2f
write (localhost): Connection refused
write (localhost): Connection refused
write (localhost): Connection refused
Removing intermediate container 0f34b430fc2f
```

Comment: can you ping localhost?

Comment: Yes putting a ping in the dockerfile shows localhost as 127.0.0.1

Comment: `localhost` is always “this container”, even in a Dockerfile (which launches an implicit container for each `RUN` step).  You probably want to create this file in the build context and `COPY` it in.

Comment: Any special tweaks in /etc/ssh/ssh_config?

Comment: Prior to running the ssh-keyscan I issue the folowing commands: RUN apt-get install -y ssh
RUN mkdir -p /home/sshkeys
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /home/sshkeys/id_rsa 
RUN touch /home/sshkeys/authorized_keys
RUN cat /home/sshkeys/id_rsa.pub >> /home/sshkeys/authorized_keys
RUN ./etc/init.d/ssh start 
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: @DavidMaze if you look at his docker file, he is manually starting a ssh server in the docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start `sshd` in same layer as `ssh-keyscan`, it's not started by default in new layer, so just couple the commands in same `RUN`:

```
RUN \
  ./etc/init.d/ssh start && \
  ssh-keyscan localhost >> /home/postgres/.ssh/known_hosts
```